# error - Linq query returns true or false if Null value in the row

Tags: c#, linq

The DataTable 'IsActive1' field return empty value.

[image]

I have written Linq query,

[image]

But, It occured error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Read the error message. It is telling you that `bool` can never be `null`. Maybe you need to use `bool?` or you need to evaluate if it is equal to `false`

Comment: You can change <bool> to <object> to get rid of error (only first occurrence, not 2nd),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write the definition of the column as `bool?` if you expect to be `null`.

```
myRow.Field<bool?>("IsActive1") == null ? true: myRow.Field<bool?>("Active1") ...
```